# Sorting dropdowns based on their contents

Tags: javascript, sorting

So I have a sort that is alphabetizing a dropdown:

```
$(".product-actions select").each(function() {   
// Sort all the options by text. I could easily sort these by val.
$(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}));
```

});

The product-class element can contain two types of dropdowns. One that display colors and one that display sizes.  This sort works perfectly for colors. However, in sizes I didn't account for clothing sizing and shoe sizing. Alphabetizing shoes sizes is great, but with clothing I want it to display from the smallest size to the largest and it becomes a problem.

Here is how the size dropdowns appear:

Shoes

```
<select class="size" data-option-key="size" data-priority="0">
  <option value="color" selected="selected">size</option>
  <option value="05"><span>05 - $198.00</span></option>
  <option value="06"><span>06 - $198.00</span></option><option value="06.5">
</select>
```

Clothing (sizes range from XS, S, M, L, XL)

```
<select class="size" data-option-key="size" data-priority="0">
  <option value="color" selected="selected">size</option>
  <option value="L(14-16)"><span>L(14-16) - $158.00</span></option>
  <option value="M(10-12)"><span>M(10-12) - $158.00</span></option>
  <option value="S(6-8)"><span>S(6-8) - $158.00</span></option>
  <option value="XL(18)"><span>XL(18) - $158.00</span></option>
  <option value="XS(2-4)"><span>XS(2-4) - $158.00</span></option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to for these two differently. Can anyone give me some advice on how to handle this sorting?

**Note - In the shoe dropdown, that price is being added on after the size.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use an JSON object and to use that for your compare function.
It's quiet simple:

```
var shirtSizes = { "XS" : "0", "S" : "1", "M" : "2", "L" : "3", "XL" : "4"}
```

then use your compare function while looking up values in the object.

```
return shirtSizes[a.text] == shirtSizes[b.text] ? 0 : shirtSizes[a.text] < shirtSizes[b.text] ? -1 : 1
```